# How is a yes/no question, asking whether it's possible to add a button to a form, "too broad"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, needs-more-focus

I [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42787559/can-you-add-a-button-to-a-userform-in-excel) the other day, a very basic n00b question, and ultimately it's a binary, yes/no, question.

Yet now I have 5 downvotes and it's marked to get closed for being "too broad".  How is a yes/no question too broad?  I don't see how the relevant section from the help center applies.

> too broad - if your question could be answered by an entire book, or
>   has many valid answers, it's probably too broad for our format
>
> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow down the
>   answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few
>   paragraphs.

I am inclined to think that the people downvoting and marking for closure don't understand the question, especially given that no one even attempted to formally answer it.  Even though it's a basic question, I wasn't able to find info anywhere else about it, and since I don't know much about the environment nor the language, I figured I would ask.

Comment: The problem with your question is that a good answer *wouldn't* be just yes or no. It would either be no with an explanation of why or yes with an explanation of how. You essentially asked the community to create a button in a user form from scratch. I don't know how much code that would be but apparently it'd be enough for those who closed it to consider it too long.

Comment: In almost all cases you don't want to ask the community for a solution and make them start from scratch. You'd have to be certain that the answer you're looking for is going to be rather short (and your question should probably still show an attempt, even if none of the code is going to end up being useful).

Comment: It's actually ridiculously easy once you find the right UI element to bring it up. I don't think the amount of time to write a paragraph or three and post 1 or 2 screenshots is excessive.  I have seen highly detailed, long winded answers many times on SEs, even on meta's.  Did I mention it was a n00b question? That means any answerers would be responding to a 0 lvl question, which is the trivial level.

Comment: .... and most of those types of questions should be answered by going to the sources, the tutorials and such. I'm no expert on the subject of your question, but if it were a Java question, I'd likely have down-voted it for not showing or telling (in adequate detail) about your own attempts at a solution and going into further detail of exactly what you found in your research.

Comment: Would you have accepted an answer that just said "Yes"? If you wouldn't it is not a yes/no-question.

Comment: You can see I made 90% of an answer in 2 sentences. I did qualify I was a n00b. You guys' philosophy is sound, but this is an edge case where it's ridiculously overarticulate and cumbersome.

Comment: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/7274/31260)

Comment: `this is an edge case where it's ridiculously overarticulate and cumbersome.` Agreed. Those edge cases tend to end up as  collateral damage. There's no good way to avoid that, unfortunately - it's impossible to formulate a guideline that everyone can understand and agree on, yet accounts for every possible edge case in existence.

Answer (score 9):

Why would you think a newb question would be *less* prone to broadness? Usually, they're *more* prone, as they want a detailed tutorial covering all the steps from A-Z with various common pitfalls listed for each.

In this case, there's a trivial question that's barely worth asking that is, in fact, answerable in one word, or perhaps a sentence at the very most, but that's not something that helps anybody much. Beyond that, there's a whole host of possible *actual* questions that could be constructed that would make more sense, but are difficult to enumerate fully, and it's that [hunch that you really have a broader question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) that drove the close votes, I suspect.

In cases where you could reasonably be expected to just, oh I don't know, fire up the development environment and spend 30 seconds trying it, the standards are a bit higher. And when you haven't gotten as far as that, the suspicion that the problem you think you have is not the real one becomes very strong.

Comment: Generally speaking, I would agree with you. However, specifically, once I found the right toolbar, it was trivial to do what I wanted, even as a n00b.  However, I didn't know what I didn't know, and therefore I didn't know if what I wanted to do was even possible.