# Does it depend on the answer whether a question is off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I've always been reluctant to ask questions where the answer might be just "no", or "this is not possible". For good reasons. Such questions seem to be received poorly. Also, answers that basically say "no, this is not possible" are not well received, in many cases.

1. Why?
2. Is it really fair if the answer to a question is important in deciding whether it is off-topic? The person who asks it does not know the answer, so they don't have a way to know beforehand if their question is on-topic or not.
3. Does this mean that "is X possible?" questions are always bad?
4. Can we have a "this question is off-topic because it can be answered with 'no, that is not possible'" close reason? (sorry for the sarcasm.)

For me this is really an unwelcoming part of Stack Overflow, and I would like to discuss this with the community. Please note that if the answer to that question were "Yes this is possible, just use `CallKit.endCurrentCellularCall()`, see the docs here", it wouldn't have been downvoted and it wouldn't have received two close-votes.

Why am I asking? Because of [iOS: Is it possible to Programatically disconnect a call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58252493/754705). It received 6 downvotes, and I have no idea why. It received 2 close votes before I answered it. After I answered it, it received no more close votes. The close-vote-explanation for "too broad" says "Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer." - Well, the question is very specific and it had enough detail for me to answer it. I don't even see which details could be added to the question to make it easier to answer. It's one of those questions where either you know the answer or you don't know it. There is no ambiguity in the question, and the answer is very straightforward.

One person told me in a comment that I shouldn't answer questions which should "clearly be closed as too broad". I asked why they are off-topic and got no response. Please explain to me why they are off-topic, because for me it is not clear at all.

Comment: Almost all "Can I do X" questions can be asked as "How do I do X" where you explain why you think that X is not possible and show what you have tried. The first type of question can only be answered with Yes or No. The second one can be used to to show you alternative ways how to achieve your goal. In general, asking Yes/No questions on SO doesn't work very well.

Comment: @BDL: well.. if I see a yes/no-answer and the answer is "yes", I usually don't answer with just "yes", but I also explain how to do something. E.g. if someone asks "is it possible to delete a file with NSFileManager?", I wouldn't answer "yes", but "yes, use NSFileManager.removeItemAtUrl". (I'm not saying that this would be a good question.) - or if someone asks me "do you know what the time is?", we answer with the time and not with "yes". I think a little bit of empathy is a good thing, even for programmers!

Comment: In the end, there is already a lot of discussions about this problem available: [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183177/question-closed-because-yes-no-answer), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258630/where-is-the-line-for-yes-no-questions), [3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345493/how-is-a-yes-no-question-asking-whether-its-possible-to-add-a-button-to-a-form), [4](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337245/how-should-you-respond-to-a-yes-or-no-question).

Comment: Note, that even when you would reformulate this specific question as a "How can I..." question, it would be still too broad since it doesn't show the slightest attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: It's worth asking if that question is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33552255/hang-up-disconnect-end-call-programmatically-using-swift-ios-8-9). Yes, it talks about Bluetooth, but it does cover why there's no call API

Comment: Related: [Should I answer “is it possible?” type of questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270933/215552) and, on [meta.se]: [Question closed because yes/no answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183177/194720)

Comment: One could argue the question is slightly confusing since it asks if it can disconnect a call but in describing what they want it sounds like they actually want to be able to block calls, not hang up on people. I can also see people thinking the OP is trying to do something malicious and sometimes people down vote if they think that's the case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if this is quite answering your question, more some thoughts around the theme of your question, but I find it quite difficult to write answers saying "no, you can't do this":

1. It's often hard to expand on them - for a "yes" answer you can show how to do it, but that isn't always possible for a "no" answer. Sometimes you can try to explain why.
2. It's difficult to be sure. It's much easier to prove a postive than a negative, and a some of the time there might be a convoluted and unsatisfactory workaround to kind of do what they want.
3. It stands to become unhelpfully wrong if things change. Obviously this applies to any answer to an extent, but usually features are added rather than removed.
4. Bad news isn't always well received.

In some conclusion: I do think that a question with a "no" answer can be on-topic. I could even come up with at least one example that I've answered like that (and the answer wasn't hugely well-received by everyone, nor my attempts to close subsequent questions as duplicates). However, it's hard to do well, and definitively so it's often tempting just to write a comment of "no, I  don't think you can".